# Is it possible to use a method from one parent class to implement an abstract method from another parent class?

Tags: c++, oop, overriding, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I've got the following classes:

```c++
class ServoPart {
private:
    bool move() {
        /* move implementation for a singular servo */
    }
}

struct RoboPart {
    virtual void doJob() =0;
    virtual bool move() =0;
}

class Claw : public ServoPart, RoboPart {
private:
    void doJob() {/* implementation */}
}

class Arm : RoboPart {
private:
    ServoPart major, minor;

    void doJob() {/* implementation */}
    bool move() {/* implementation for two servos */}
}
```

Now, `Arm` works since it implements both, `doJob` and `move`. `Claw` however doesn't work because it would be an abstract class since it doesn't implement move (even though it has `move` from the base class). When I add `bool move() override;` to `Claw`, I get an *undefined reference to `vtable for Claw'* failure from the linker.

Is it possible to do this somehow? Or do I need to rename `ServoPart#move` to `ServoPart#moveStep` and call that from a function `move` in Claw?

Comment: Why doesn't `class ServoPart` inherit from `struct RoboPart`? `call that from a function move in Claw?` You are searching for `class Claw ... { bool move() { return ServoPart::move(); } }`? `private:
    bool move() ` Wouldn't you want `protected:` here then?

Comment: @KamilCuk Because not every `ServoPart` is a `RoboPart`. The class Arm for example has two `ServoParts` which are no `RoboParts`. I'll add that to the OP.
From your edit I'm guessing there's no way around calling `ServoPart::move()` in `Claw::move()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here, is that all your methods are private, so no of them can be called from outside the defining class, not even from a subclass.

Assuming that the *blocking* `private:` declarations can be removed, there is no problem in using a method from a superclass to implement a method from another superclass **provided it is accessible**, but the implementation must be explicit:

```
class ServoPart {
protected:
    bool move() {
        /* move implementation for a singular servo */
    }
};

class Claw : public ServoPart, RoboPart {
private:
    void doJob() {/* implementation */}
    bool move() {
        return ServoPart::move();
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 2):

How about creating another Base class "Part" & then inherit ServoPart & RoboPart from it

```
struct Part {
    virtual bool move() = 0;
};

class ServoPart : public Part{
private:
    bool move() {
        /* move implementation for a singular servo */
    }
};

struct RoboPart : public Part{
    virtual void doJob() = 0;
};

class Claw : public ServoPart, RoboPart {
private:
    void doJob() {/* implementation */}
    bool move() {/* implementation */}
};

class Arm : RoboPart {
private:
    ServoPart major, minor;

    void doJob() {/* implementation */}

    bool move() {/* implementation for two servos */}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried fiddling a bit to understand if the `using` statement might have been useful but seems it does not do what you want.

One possible solution is to use an intermediary class and manually invoke the implementation you want, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class ServoPart {
public:
    virtual bool move() {
        std::cout << "servopart::move" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

struct RoboPart {
    virtual void doJob() =0;
    virtual bool move() =0;
};


struct ServoRoboPart: public ServoPart, RoboPart
{
    virtual bool move(){ ServoPart::move(); return true; };
};

class Claw : public ServoRoboPart {
public:
    void doJob() {std::cout << "claw::doJob" << std::endl;}
};

class Arm : RoboPart {
public:
    void doJob() {std::cout << "arm::doJob" << std::endl;}
    bool move() {std::cout << "arm::move" << std::endl; return true;}
};

int main()
{
    Claw c;
    Arm a;
    a.move();
    a.doJob();
    c.move();
    c.doJob();
}
```

For this to work `ServoRoboPart` must be able to see `ServoPart::move`, so it has to be at least `protected`. The other visibility changes are to allow it to run on ideone: https://ideone.com/ar5OQl

Output is

```
arm::move
arm::doJob
servopart::move
claw::doJob
```

as intended.

Comment: Thank you! I honestly don't quite understand why/how this works. Could I theoretically make `ServoPart::move` virtual and leave out the intermediary class? Also, why is it `using ServoPart:move` instead of `using ServoRoboPart::move`?

Comment: That is a mistake, that line is not necessary. No, I tried and making `move` virtual wouldn't allow `Claw` to compile, the intermediate class is necessary if you want to avoid implementing the method again in `Claw`. I updated the answer with the correct code.